# Exact definition of a regular open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space.

(1) A subset $A$ of $X$ is regular open iff $A={\rm int}\ \bar{A}$.

(2) An **open** subset $A$ of $X$ is regular open iff $A={\rm int}\ \bar{A}$.

(1) implies that **any** subset $A$ of $X$ is regular closed as long as $A={\rm int}\ \bar{A}$, whereas (2) presupposes that $A$ be open in the first place. I saw both definitions around. Which one is correct? (I understand that a regular open set is open.)

Answer (score 3):

(1) implies that $A$ is open since $A$ [is the interior of some other set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157723/proving-set-of-interiors-is-open), so the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Ths first is prefered.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It seems to me that "preferred" depends on the contexts. One of the common uses of regular open sets is to produce a Boolean algebra, where the lattice of all open sets is only a Heyting algebra. In that context, one might prefer version (2) because one is already working in the context of open sets. Someone who is enthusiastic about Galois connections might even prefer a definition like "$A$ equals the exterior of its exterior."